# jQuery - How to select all checkboxes EXCEPT a specific one?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a jQuery selector that looks like this ...

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(event) {
  // DO STUFF HERE
}
```

Everything was working well until I was asked to add another checkbox that has nothing to do with the original checkboxes. How do I create a selector for all checkboxes except for one? Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$('input:checkbox:not("#thatCheckboxId")').click(function(event) {
  // DO STUFF HERE
}
```

Just give the checkbox in question a unique `id=""`

Comment: You can combine that into one selector: `$('input:checkbox:not("#thatCheckboxId")')`, which is much more efficient: http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

```
$("input:checkbox").not(":eq(0)")
```

being the "0" the index of your desired checkbox (in this case the first on the DOM)

Answer (score 4):

Well.. we need to know more about the HTML for a specific answer, but there are two methods that I can think of.

1) if you know the name of the one that you don't want then remove that one with `not`

```
$("input:checkbox").not('#the_new_checkbox_id').click(function(event) {
  // DO STUFF HERE
}
```

2) use something that the correct inputs have in common to select them.

```
$("input:checkbox[name=whatItIsNamed]").click(function(event) {
  // DO STUFF HERE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If all the checkboxes are within another element, you can select all checkboxes within that element.

Here is an example with one parent element.

```
<div class="test"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
```

The jQuery below also works with multiple divs as well:

```
<div class="test"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="test"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.test input:checkbox')
```

That selects just the checkboxes within any element with class "test".

-Sunjay03

Comment: Why do you sign your answers?

Comment: ...good question. Habbit? I used to do it all the time on forums...so it just developed from that. =) Why do you ask OT questions? :P

Comment: Because it's silly given that you're attributed here (and on most forums)

Comment: Hahaha just a habit. Doesn't add or take anything away from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i used this - dont want to select the checkbox named with "subscription" so i used "$(':checkbox:not(checkbox[name=nameofyourcheckboxyoudontwantto]').each(function(){"

```
   $('#checked_all').click(function (event) {
    var checkbox = $(".compare_checkbox").is(":checked");
    if (checkbox) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox:not(:checkbox[name=subscription])').each(function () {

            this.checked = false;
        });
    } else {
        $(':checkbox:not(:checkbox[name=subscription])').each(function () {
            this.checked = true;
        });
    }  });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGVpi.png)