# How to check all checkbox except special ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to check all but one item [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523687/jquery-how-to-select-all-checkboxes-except-a-specific-one) works, however I want to except more than one item, such as:

```
var ingore_ids = [1,2,3];
```

Then this code does not work:

```
$('#checkAll').click(function () {
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).not(ignore_ids).prop('checked', this.checked);)
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML to your question too, please?

Comment: Have you tried like your link said to do **$("input:checkbox").not(":eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3)")** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your logic is that `not()` expects a selector or array of elements to exclude from the current collection.

To fix this issue you can use `join()` to build a selector from the `id` values contained in the array, something like this:

```js
var ingore_ids = [1, 2, 3];

$('#checkAll').click(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').not('#' + ingore_ids.join(',#')).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> check some...<br />
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="1" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="4" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="5" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="6" /><br />
```

An alternative would be to provide a function to `not()` which checks if the `id` of the current checkbox is not in the array:

```js
var ingore_ids = [1,2,3];

$('#checkAll').click(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').not(function(i, el) {
    return ingore_ids.indexOf(parseInt(el.id, 10)) !== -1;
  }).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> check some...<br />
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="1" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="4" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="5" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="6" /><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way use `each` and `attr` method.

```
var ignores = [1,2,3];

    $('#checkAll').click(function() {
      $('input:checkbox').each(function(index, item) {

        var id = parseInt($(item).attr('id'));

        if(ignores.indexOf(id) == -1){

         $(item).prop('checked', 'checked')
        }
      });
    });
```

```js
var ignores = [1,2,3];

$('#checkAll').click(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').each(function(index, item) {
   
    var id = parseInt($(item).attr('id'));
    
    if(ignores.indexOf(id) == -1){
     
     $(item).prop('checked', 'checked')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> check some...<br />
</label>
<p>check all ignore 1,2,3</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="1" />1<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" />2<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" />3<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="4" />4<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="5" />5<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="6" />6<br />
```